# How do I use update multiple rows in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I get batches of inventory items to update and I would like to eliminate calling the stored procedure multiple times and instead call it once with multiple values. I have done similar in oracle with the parameters as an array trick. I would like to do something similar for SQL Server.

- I have a comma separated list of Sku
- I have a comma separated list of Quantity.
- I have a comma separated list of StoreIds.

The standard update is

```
Update Inventory 
set quantity = @Quantity 
where sku = @Sku and StoreId = @StoreId;
```

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE Inventory
(
    [Sku] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Quantity] DECIMAL NULL DEFAULT 0.0, 
    [StoreId] INT NOT NULL 
}
```

My bad attempt at doing this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateList
    (@Sku varchar(max), 
     @Quantity varchar(max), 
     @StoreId varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @n int = 0;
   DECLARE @skuTable TABLE = SELECT CONVERT(value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Sku, ',');
   DECLARE @quantityTable = SELECT CONVERT(value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Quantity, ',');
   DECLARE @StoreIdTable = SELECT CONVERT(value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@StoreId , ',');

   WHILE @n < @skuTable.Count
   BEGIN
       UPDATE inventoryItem 
       SET Quantity = @quantityTable 
       WHERE Sku = @skuTable AND StoreId = @StoreIdTable;

       SELECT @n = @n + 1;
   END
END
```

I am open to using temp tables as parameters instead of comma separated. This is being called from an Entity Framework 6 context object from the front end system.

Comment: look into Table-Value Parameters and then do a JOIN. Avoid doing it as a loop if possible. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad practice to pass tabular values in this way. 

Best solution is to pass it as a "user defined table type", if possible, 
otherwise, it's better to get JSON/XML parameter 
and then you can update your table like this:

```
--[ Parameters ]--
DECLARE @json AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[{"Sku":"A","Quantity":1.4,"StoreId":1},{"Sku":"B","Quantity":2.5,"StoreId":2},{"Sku":"C","Quantity":3.6,"StoreId":3}]';


--[ Bulk Update ]--
UPDATE  inventoryItem
SET     Quantity        =   I.Quantity
FROM    inventoryItem   AS  T
JOIN    OPENJSON(@json) WITH (Sku NVARCHAR(50), Quantity DECIMAL(5,1),StoreId INT)  AS I
ON      I.Sku           =   T.Sku
AND     I.StoreId       =   T.StoreId
```

Comment: Any bonus points for the equivalent for an insert?  I like the JSON version as I can easily serialize the objects I am saving.

Comment: I figured out the insert version.  I am adding the answer below.  Maybe I should make a new question and answer it myself but this information is worth while to have available.

Comment: does performance will effect when we use the table type to pass the records instead of JSON/XML ?

Comment: table type should have better performance, as it does not need to parse the json, and also should take less data transportation. However, ms-sql is very efficient with parsing JSONs, so I wouldn't give it so much weight, unless you're passing big data in each call

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad practice to pass tabular values as varchar columns parameters, 
but if you still want to go this way, here is a working code:

```
--[ Parameters ]--
DECLARE @Sku        VARCHAR(max)    = 'A,B,C', 
        @Quantity   VARCHAR(max)    = '1.4,2.5,3.6', 
        @StoreId    VARCHAR(max)    = '1,2,3'


--[ Converting VARCHAR Parameters to Table #Inventory ]--
DROP    TABLE IF EXISTS #Sku
SELECT  IDENTITY(int, 1,1)  AS RowNum,
        T.value
INTO    #Sku
FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@Sku, ',') AS T

DROP    TABLE IF EXISTS #Quantity
SELECT  IDENTITY(int, 1,1)  AS RowNum,
        T.value
INTO    #Quantity
FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@Quantity, ',')    AS T

DROP    TABLE IF EXISTS #StoreId
SELECT  IDENTITY(int, 1,1)  AS RowNum,
        T.value
INTO    #StoreId
FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@StoreId, ',') AS T


DROP    TABLE IF EXISTS #Inventory
SELECT  Sku.value       AS Sku,
        Quantity.value  AS Quantity,
        StoreId.value   AS StoreId
INTO    #Inventory
FROM    #Sku        AS Sku
JOIN    #Quantity   AS Quantity ON Quantity.RowNum = Sku.RowNum
JOIN    #StoreId    AS StoreId  ON StoreId.RowNum = Sku.RowNum


--[ Bulk Update ]--
UPDATE  inventoryItem
SET     Quantity        =   I.Quantity
FROM    inventoryItem   AS  T
JOIN    #Inventory      AS  I
ON      I.Sku           =   T.Sku
AND     I.StoreId       =   T.StoreId
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are correct for updates and answered my question.  But I wanted to add the insert here as I am sure someone will be looking for both.  Maybe I will come back an make a new question and answer it myself.

I think the JSON version is best for my issue because I am doing entity framework and serializing an object to JSON is a trivial task.  The basic process is to create an inline temp table from the json string.  Calling out the objects via a simple dot notation string. I would suggest making the object passed in as simple as possible and preferably one level of properties.

```
create or alter Procedure bulkInventoryInsert( @json AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT into inventory
SELECT Sku, Quantity, StoreId FROM  
OPENJSON(@json)  
WITH(Sku varchar(200)  '$.Sku', 
     Quantity decimal(5,1) '$.Quantity', 
     StoreId INT '$.StoreId');   
END

DECLARE @json AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[{"Sku":"A","Quantity":1.4,"StoreId":2},{"Sku":"B","Quantity":2.5,"StoreId":3},{"Sku":"C","Quantity":3.6,"StoreId":2}]';
EXECUTE bulkInventoryInsert @json;
```

The key part to recognize is this section here:

```
SELECT Sku, Quantity, StoreId FROM  
OPENJSON(@json)  
WITH(Sku varchar(200)  '$.Sku', 
     Quantity decimal(5,1) '$.Quantity', 
     StoreId INT '$.StoreId');
```

This is creating a temp table with columns that match the table that it will be inserted into.  The "WITH" portion specifies the column name, type, and where in the Json string to get the value.

I hope this will help.  Maybe when I get time I will do a question and answer for this.